# How To Pass CloudFormation Outputs To A CodeBuild Stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I have 2 CloudFormation and CodeBuild CodePipeline stages:

```
        - Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Deploy"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CloudFormation"
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: "CREATE_UPDATE"
                Capabilities: "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_IAM"
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn
                StackName: !Ref CFNStackName
                TemplatePath: !Sub "BuildArtifact::${ArtifactName}"
                TemplateConfiguration: BuildArtifact::CFTemplateConfig.json
                ParameterOverrides: !Sub '{"Env": "${Env}"}'
              Name: "CloudFormation-step"
              Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildArtifact
              RunOrder: 1
          Name: "Deploy"
        - Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Test"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CodeBuild"
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildTest
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              Name: "Test"
              Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
              RunOrder:
```

The CloudFormation stage is creating an ALB. I would like to pass that ALB's ARN to the CodeBuild stage. How do I pass the ALB ARN to the CodeBuild buildspec.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your CFN template returns the ALB ARN in its outputs, e.g. called `AlbArn`, then you can provide a [namespace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html) for it and use the namespace later to get the value.

For example (may need some further adjustments):

```
        - Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Deploy"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CloudFormation"
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: "CREATE_UPDATE"
                Capabilities: "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_IAM"
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn
                StackName: !Ref CFNStackName
                TemplatePath: !Sub "BuildArtifact::${ArtifactName}"
                TemplateConfiguration: BuildArtifact::CFTemplateConfig.json
                ParameterOverrides: !Sub '{"Env": "${Env}"}'
              Name: "CloudFormation-step"
              Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildArtifact
              Namespace: CloudFromationDeployNamespace # <--- namespace
              RunOrder: 1
          Name: "Deploy"
        - Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Test"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CodeBuild"
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildTest
                EnvironmentVariables: | # <- pass the AlbArn as ENV variable
                    {
                      "ALB_NAME": "#{CloudFromationDeployNamespace.AlbArn}"
                    }   
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              Name: "Test"
              Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}            
              RunOrder:
```

Comment: This is the output I wrote:
 `Outputs:
  AlbArn:
    Description: The ARN of the
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancer
    Export:
      Name: ALBName`
Does it have to reference anything about the `CloudFromationDeployNamespace` we provioded?

Comment: @gumluvinisgoodluvin This should be enough, Did you check, does it not work as expected?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I added the namespace and the output. But when I try to echo the EnvironmentVariable - it give me an empty output

Comment: @gumluvinisgoodluvin It should be output name `AlbArn`, not the export value `ALBName` . I editted the `EnvironmentVariables`.